# Using Magento Observers to display a popup of the last item added to the cart

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am trying to use observers in Magento 1.7.0.2 to catch when a product is added to cart.

After that event has happened (I believe it is the event checkout_cart_add_product_complete) I would like to show a popup that gives an overview of the product that the customer has just bought, as it would be seen in an item line in the cart.

I have tried to build a module that would catch this event, but I can't find a way to test if I have the same event, what models I need to use or pretty much anything.

So far, I have this written

```
public function checkoutCartAddProductComplete (Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
    $session = Mage::getSingleton("checkout/session")->addSuccess($message);
    $message = $this->__('Changed! You added %s to your shopping cart.', Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($product->getName()));
    $session->addSuccess($message);
}
```

However I took that code from the Internet, and it doesn't seem to be working.

There is something in \app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\controllers\CartController.php (around line 205) that shows the eventDispatcher and then the code that displays a message - however I'm not sure how to actually transplant this to a module, short of copying the whole file and overwriting it.

I'm trying to do this as a module so I can take it across various projects, but it is turning out to be a project on it's own...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You $session variable is set like:

`$session = Mage::getSingleton("checkout/session")->addSuccess($message);`

But at the same time you `$message` is not yet set.

So when after you set your message and are trying to save you message you are actually doing.

`Mage::getSingleton("checkout/session")->addSuccess($message)->addSuccess($message);`

Remove `->addSuccess($message);` from your session variable and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for that.

Is there a way that I can verify that I'm trying to hook the correct Event?

I'm trying to simply use `die();` but it's not dying, which to me suggests I'm not actually using the right one.

Comment: @ChrisWells `Mage::log('Did my event fire?');` is a great way to check if your observer is firing, make sure you have developer mode turned on in your config > developer and look in var/log/system.log.  die(); is fine though :)

Comment: @ChrisWells I think that observer is fine, probably a XML error

Comment: Seems that the event triggered, but in the wrong place. It was for the actual cart rather than the product page adding to the cart...

Comment: I got it working, however my IDE says that my use of `$this->__('text in here');` isn't valid. Is there a reason why this might be?

In fact, it is also saying that in `$product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();` getProduct() is not found in Varien_Event...

Comment: @ChrisWells http://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-7/

As for trying to work out the model calls, mage log again comes in extremely handy a model such as     `[order_create_model] => Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Sales_Order_Create Object` turns into `->getSalesOrderCreate()`